# Adding datetime column with seconds column using awk

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a csv file like this below

```
DateTime                Keywords    CallDuration       CallEndTime
2018-12-18 18:36:55    cars,petrol    120
2018-12-19 15:10:19    diesel          90
2018-12-17 15:10:19    bus             86
```

I want to add DateTime and CallDuration column and corresponding sum should be placed in CallEndTime column,

How can I do that using awk ?

Comment: And the value of `CallDuration` is in what unit of time? Seconds? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: I can see a pending edit from another account adding information about the unit of time. I have voted to reject, because I don't know if it is the same person. If it is, please log in with the original account and edit the question.

Comment: If you are using GNU awk, you have some built-in [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions). You can write a couple of short functions to convert the YMD HMS timestamp to epoch seconds, add the duration, and format the total back to YMD HMS format.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is tab separated.

```
awk -F$'\t' '
    BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
    NR!=1{
        ("date -Iseconds -d \""$1"\"" | getline startdate)
        ("date \"+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" -d \""startdate" + "$3" seconds\"" | getline $4)
    }1' file.csv
```

- `BEGIN{OFS="\t"}` Set output field separator to tab.
- `NR!=1{...}` run the command in the brackets for any line except header.

  - `("date -Iseconds -d \""$1"\"" | getline startdate)` Convert date to a format which is easy to read for date command and save it as `startdate` variable.
  - `("date \"+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" -d \""startdate" + "$3" seconds\"" | getline $4)` Add seconds from field `$3` to `startdate` and save it as field `$4`.
- `1` print the row.

---

If the file is not tab-separated, you need to fix it with something like this: `sed -i -r 's/\s\s+/\t/' file.csv`.